# Design view is missing in sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

IS there any update to SharePoint designer 2013 where design view will be visible for .aspx pages.

Earlier version had that feature.what made Microsoft to remove the feature.i feel productivity will go down because of this.

let me know is there ant third party tool to get this benefit.

Answer (score 4):

The only answer is "No."

There is no Design View in SharePoint Designer 2013, and there are currently no plans to get that functionality back into the product. Microsoft encourages the use of Visual Studio instead, or any other editor suitable for web development with HTML5, like Dreamweaver et al.

SharePoint specific functionality like DVWPs and other web part properties will have to be managed in code view and will require a good understanding of the make-up of these web parts.

A lot of people are not happy about that. Others applaud Microsoft for taking that approach and preventing Power users with limited skills to mess around with SPD and there are lots of discussions of the topic on the web.

So, no, there is currently no tool that will give you the full functional preview of a web part page like SharePoint Designer 2010 used to do.

But, you can always try to open the 2013 page with SPD 2010. In many cases you will see that it renders the bits that it can recognize, but it may choke on some of the HTML5 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Saying the reasoning behind the changes is With SharePoint Server 2013 embracing new web standards for client side rendering of pages such as JavaScript, JSON, and OData, there is no longer a need to support a visual web page editor within SharePoint Designer.

See the post below from Microsoft

https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/10/changes-to-the-design-view-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/